# xml layout in android

Tags: android, xml, layout

So i'm having some issues with getting my application to look the way i want it to.

So the first issue i'm having is, i want to have small icons on the left side which is always visable to the end user. And they have the option to take it out (pull the icons to the right), and look what they do (i'll add text on the left side of the icons). What kind of view would i have to use?

Also whenever i try to make icons they always get a grey background eventhough i have transparent background in ps.

finally, how do i get a photo to show up from a website? i'll have my own database of photos i want to be shown, but how do i get those to appear? i tried things such as imageview, but that's something different..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For partially visible navigation drawer, follow the link : [Android - How to implement a NavigationDrawer that is partially visible at all times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978248/android-how-to-implement-a-navigationdrawer-that-is-partially-visible-at-all-t)
2. For clickable icons, you are probably using `android:src` for ImageButton. Instead set image as `android:background`
3. For images to be loaded from the web, use `WebView` and simply using `<img src="example.com/xyz.jpg">` will do the work.