# Moving a view left of the screen

Tags: android, animation

My android app UI have two parts- a menu bar (blue color) and content area (gray color).
Here red is the device screen.
The menu bar should open from left to right whene the hamburger menu is clicked.
I tried with ViewSwitcher but that shows only one view at a time.
What is the right method to implement it?[image]
UPDATE: I am looking for the solution for API level 10  onwards.

Comment: try if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978248/android-how-to-implement-a-navigationdrawer-that-is-partially-visible-at-all-t) gives a clue.

Answer (score 1):

In the newest version of the ADT you can select Navigation Drawer as navigation type when you create a new Activity. This automatically implements this type of navigation for you.

Alternatively, check out this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: I need to support API level 10.

Comment: I believe the newest version of the ADT also provides compatibility projects that are automatically included if you specify low api support when creating your Android project. I'm not sure if this includes compatibility for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with the navigation bar overlaying the content, then use the navigation drawer as suggested.

Alternatively check out:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos

There are many open source libraries that you can pick and test, and then decide which one to grab the code for.