# Android Sliding Panel with Showing icons only when it is collapsed

Tags: android, slidingmenu, slidingpanelayout

I want to implement sliding Menu like below images ,I am using SlidingPaneLayout to create Left Sliding Menu but How i can make it to behave like below images.

[image]

Now when some one close it by Either top left icons click or by drag to left it should be close like below shown image.

[image]

This image are just for giving idea of what i am try to do in my sliding Menu .

Let me known that some known how to achieve such in android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - How to implement a NavigationDrawer that is partially visible at all times?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978248/android-how-to-implement-a-navigationdrawer-that-is-partially-visible-at-all-t)

Comment: @Korcholis Yes But in my requirement i want my Sliding Menu have Right icons and it should show Partially to Left side.

Comment: Hey Herry, have a look at @ManveerChawla's answer. That library he links does what you need

Comment: @Korcholis Yeah absolutely right